# Trust CA certificate on istio level

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, istio

I am using kubernetes and istio.

I need to call https service outside my mesh, and this called service using internal CA authority, which mean I need to trust the server side certificate.

Can I trust the certificate on istio level instead of each micro-service?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using cert-manager & ingress probably which will manage the ssl certificates :

you can check it out more at :

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes

you can also refer documents of istio where there option for HTTPS for managed gateway: https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/secure-ingress/

Comment: All of this talk about ingress, Actually I need to setup egress, and I just need to trust self signed certificate